# How to make relation between several tables when relation depends on value

Tags: c#, sql

I hava table to handle "Tree" structure

```
Id Auto   - increment int (key column)
LevelType  -Int (tell where I get detailt data depend my selection
LevelParentId -Int (if node have parent node)
LevelChildId -Int (if node have child node)
DataId  -int (tell what is index for detail data)
```

then I have table where I get values to LevelType id column.
Now if user add tree node, he give name for node and specify node type. Now I want to show data from other table depend on LevelType. Example if LevelType value is 1, then detail data is in table "Comppany.
If  LevelType value is 2, then detail data is in table "Department"

I can make subquery to handle selection for LevelType, but how I can specified which table I get detail data...??

[Database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps8FF.png)

**Thanks for answer. I decide use Datset instanse**

Comment: You can try using a Document Store DB. Instead of a relational one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I guess you are complicating the storage structure for tree. Consider the following approach:</s>

**Table: Node**

- Id Auto Increment (Integer PKey) -- Represents unique NodeId for each
  node
- string NodeData -- Represents the data you want to hold
- ParentId (Integer nullable) -- Represents the Id of the parent node. Null for
  Root nodes.

Update:

Try using SQL CASE in the following manner:

```
CASE 
WHEN LevelTypeId = 1 THEN (SELECT FROM Company Table)
WHEN LevelTypeId = 2 THEN (SELECT FROM Department Table)
END
```

However, remember that cases must select same type of data for the sql to work.

**Update 2:**

"How to make relation between several tables when relation depends on value"

Do you mean how do you make foreign key relationships amongst your Tree table and the Company/Department tables because the relation depends on the value of LevelType column being 1/2??

One way to do it is to have this relationship handled in your Data Access Layer C# Code. Otherwise, refactor the DB in a way like: have just one table for content (i.e. Company/Department both will be stored in same tables). Keep common properties as columns while specific ones in a XML column. Serialize the Company/Department object to store into XML column.

Comment: Tree work fine. The problem is how I can show right form when user select node.... I can make it with C# code but i want that database relation is also correct

Comment: @Ari - Can you add screenshot of the table structures/Relational Diagram of your DB. May be then people here can help.

Comment: If I understand the challenge correctly - It again comes down to the way you have designed table/relations. Anyways - can you try SQL CASE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)